# Does FreeRTOS guarantee the first timer tick to be exactly 1ms?

Tags: arm, freertos, cortex-m

I am implementing software watchdogs to ensure that a 1kHz task is executing within its allotted deadline (i.e. 1ms). But I am wondering if there's exactly **1ms** between the 1kHz starting and tick 1.

From my understanding, this is what happens when FreeRTOS starts

```
vPortSetupTimerInterrupt(); // Tick 0 starts
...
prvPortStartFirstTick(); // Context switch

// After the context switch, the 1kHz task starts
```

Between tick 0 and tick 1, the 1kHz  task doesn't get a full 1ms to do useful work because some time was spent on calling `vPortSetupTimerInterrupt()` to `prvPortStartFirstTick()`. Is this correct? And if so, is this a cause for concern? Or is the extra delay time so short that it is negligible?

I am developing on ARM Cortex M4 (STM32F302 series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that executing from vPortSetupTimerInterrupt() to prvPortStartFirstTick() (not sure what that function is, not a FreeRTOS supplied one) does take some time - as does executing any instruction.  If it is a concern or not depends on your application - but if it is a concern then you are probably not going to every get exactly 1ms to the first tick.  Think about doing it the other way around - say the first task starts before the timer is started - then the first task will have to be the one that starts the time - so again you are going to spend some time in the task doing something other than what you want the task to be doing.